# How to enable WordPress plugin shortcode for All WordPress multisite

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using Wordpress multisite. And I have 5 sites. When I install a few plugins for Site 1 and use its short codes for Site 1.

It works fine in Site 1 but I use the same short code for other site it does not work.

So I want the solution for it how to enable its short codes to work in other sites.
Please help me.

Comment: is the plugin enabled on your other websites?

Comment: yes but shortcode is showing in only one site where I have created ; and not showing other site. But plugin is showing. I have 5 site so I have the same shortcode for all the. My shortcode if contact form 7 that I have created . and I wanted to use the same all the sites